# Software Recommondations to keep track of forum posts

Tags: rss, forum, notification, stack-exchange

Is there software that can keep track and notify me of new posts across messageboards and sites like StackExchange (across multiple different usernames)?

I would like it to have the following features,

- RSS Support
- Notifications

Comment: Is that "new posts across *multiple* messageboards"? A (any) RSS reader is your best bet but your success depends on the quality of the RSS feeds of the individual messageboards.

Comment: Which OS must be supported? What kind of notifications do you have in mind (mail, desktop-notifications, …)? Any budget, or must the product be free (as in "free beer")? What kind of "messageboards" must be supported (there are many different concepts, and not all of them provide interfaces for this – and even if they do, those interfaces are quite different)? Must it differenciate between messages directly addressed to you and general ones, between "areas" (boards), etc?

Comment: Please tell explicitly what message board software you want compatibility for (example: phpBB, Slashdot, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there is an RSS feed for your profile, that you can use an application like feedreader.com to track it,

> ## [FeadReader.com](http://online.feedreader.com/)
>
> Feedreader Online is one of the best Google Reader alternatives allowing you to view all of your feeds any way you want.
>   [image: FeaderReader image]

Otherwise, what I do is I use a Firefox Add-on called Distill. It basically takes snapshots of a webpage an alerts you if it has changed. You can choose to ignore and/or only look at certain elements on the page (For example, your Stack Exchange inbox). Distill is also available on Chrome, Apple, Andriod, and as a web service.

> ## [Distill Web Monitor](http://distill.io/)
>
> Distill is a web monitoring tool. It can monitor RSS feeds, a webpage or a part of webpage. Alerts in the form of pop-up, audio or emails can be received.
>
> In addition to basic page monitoring & alert, there are advanced options to give more control. The monitoring interval can be set from arange of values. Various conditions can be set for the alert action to occur.
>   [image: Distill interface]